# What's the correct value for solr 3.5 <env-entry-value>?

Tags: solr

I am trying to deploy solr 3.5 in Windows localhost. I've modified the WEB-INF\web.xml to set the solr home by adding the following:

```
<env-entry>
<env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
<env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
<env-entry-value></env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

But I don't know what's correct value for 
Plz help me!

Comment: You mentioned Windows localhost, what container (web server) are you running this in?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the location of your Solr installation like this:

```
 <env-entry-value>C:\Projects\solr-trunk\example\solr</env-entry-value>
```